# node eventEmitter usage and scope within async.waterfall call

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous

I'm trying to write an application in node that will first parse a json stirng, validate if that string contains required key/value pairs, and eventually do more processing on that data. We are using async.waterfall to call our functions as the result will need to be passed through from one function to the next.

The problem I keep running into is that of scope I believe. I'd like to emit either an 'error' or 'success' message as a part of the final callback of the waterfall, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to capture that message. The important parts of my file looks like this:

```
var MetadataIngester = function() {
    var status, returnValue;
    eventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MetadataIngester, eventEmitter);

MetadataIngester.prototype.sendEvent = function(eventType, eventMessage) {
    this.emit(eventType, eventMessage);
}

MetadataIngester.prototype.clobber = function(itemString) {
    var self = this;
    var asyncParseItem = self.parseItem;
    var asyncValidateItem = self.validateItem;
    var asyncSendvent = self.sendEvent;
    async.waterfall(
        [
            function(callback) {
                asyncParseItem(itemString, callback);
            },
           asyncValidateItem
        ],
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                asyncSendEvent.call(self, 'wtf', result);
            } else {
                asyncSendEvent.call(self, 'success', {
                    'remedia_id': 123
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

To test this, I'm doing the following:

```
describe("#clobber", function() {
    it('should emit an error event if item has not been inserted', function() {
        item = "{}";
        metadata.on('wtf', errorSpy);
        metadata.clobber(item);
        expect(errorSpy).to.have.been.called;
    });


});

describe("#sendEvent", function() {
     it('should emit an wtf event if an error event type is passed in', function() {
         metadata.on('wtf', errorSpy);
         metadata.sendEvent('wtf', {'ihateyou': 'wtf'});
         expect(errorSpy).to.have.been.called;
     });
});
```

When I run the first test, the event is emitted, but the spy is never called. However, if I call the function that emits the event directly as in the case of the second test, it works just fine, and I'm not sure why. I need to get the events captured by the test file as eventually I will be using this MetadataIngester with a queue that pulls messages off a queue and that consumer is what calls this file and expects back events so it will know what to do next.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note `var asyncSendvent` is spelled differently than `asyncSendEvent` later when called.

Comment: To better help you, it would be good to see what the functions do you are calling and how the spies are defined. Maybe you can create a fiddle? Maybe it's just a scope problem, I provided an answer to be able to make a code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your scope in a callback, use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). This keeps your code less cluttered (no magic `self`, `that`, etc):

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        this.parseItem(itemString, callback);
    }.bind(this),
    this.validateItem
], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        this.endEvent('wtf', result);
    } else {
        this.sendEvent('success', {
            'remedia_id': 123
        }.bind(this));
    }
}.bind(this));
```